# Same query different results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have checked lots of other questions with the same or similar title, and they do not have an answer that is working for my issue:

```
// Query:

SELECT *
FROM `rbs`
WHERE `rbs_id` = '92448'

// Simplified output from PHP script

[rbs_id] => 92448
[rbs_status] => 4
[start_date] => 2022-07-22 13:58:36
[end_date] => 2022-07-22 15:12:24
```

When I run that exact same query on phpMyAdmin AND MySQL command line, I get the following result:

```
[rbs_id] => 92448
[rbs_status] => 4
[start_date] => 2022-07-22 13:58:36
[end_date] => 2022-12-31 23:59:59
```

So - two of the three ways to run the query return the end date as the end of this year, which is what I am expecting to see, but in PHP, it uses the current date as the `end_date` (Refreshing the page updates the `end_date` in the result, as if something is updating the result AFTER the query with the expected date, but there is nothing that does that:

```
$query = $this->db->get($this->table);
print_r($this->db->last_query());
print_r($query->row_array());
```

I am using Codeigniter 3.1.11 query builder to construct the query, then I output the query that it generated, and copied and pasted that to phpMyAdmin and MySQL command line, so the query is the same in all cases, and it is a very simple query as you can see.

I have restarted the MySQL server, for good measure, but not fixing the issue.

And yes, for stating the obvious - I am using the same database in the PHP script, phpMyAdmin as well as in MySQL.

Any ideas what could cause the difference in results?

Comment: Is it possible that `rbs` is a view and that `end_date` changes constantly and/or there's a timezone issue and/or that `end_date` is not actually a DATETIME field and php is converting?

Comment: Good question, thanks, but no - it is a standard InnoDB table. The `end_date` is a datetime  field. All these different queries, I am running on the same server. within seconds from one another, and the MySQL commandline and phpMyAdmin consistently give the end of the year date (correct) while PHP gives the current date. I would've figured I made a mistake in my code, but I have shown that I am running the output in the script directly after running the query. It simply does not make sense to me. I am stumped.

Comment: I will suggest you to check your table `rbs` in `phpMyAdmin` multiple times before running query, if `end_date` was changing then its definitely changing by some other methods, that constantly running hint: ajax. If the `end_date` wasn't changing you can simply check your controller make sure other query that don't modify it, before or after running the query.

Comment: Data is not changing in phpMyAdmin. I checked that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's timezone issue I think
You just have to check timezone of your system as well as from script.
If both times are different then there's a problem

Comment: Thanks. Same server, same database, just different ways of accessing the data. So, it does not appear to be time zones, but @tadman mentioned this as well, and I am continuing investigating.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).